# How to fetch data out of an scanned image of a form?

Tags: python, r, opencv, image-processing

I have some data of scanned forms. The format of form is predefined and I have image of empty forms too. I want to extract that info against each value from the form. Any known solution or library in R or python for image processing in order to achieve those values can help. I have tried openCv in python for it, but not able to get success. Any solution for it?

PFA the screenshots of the both types of images I have.

Empty Form Image:-[image]
Filled Form Image:-[image]

Comment: This process is called [optical character recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) or 'OCR'. Try searching for that in combination with 'python'. Though I think you'll find it's quite difficult, especially if the forms are filled out by different people.

Comment: I have tried OCR, but when i try to pick the data using teserract , then it also treats the boxes as letter "I", which i m not able to sort out. I just need to get those values out of images. Rest thing i have figured out, using teserract. Now the problem lies, how to get those characters out of those images,  so that i can pass it to next program which will help in ocr. Basically the problem reduces to fetching characters out of the images. Character recognition i have figured out. So tried openCv for that. But still no success.

Comment: That would be good information to add to the question. If the form has some identifying markers, or a rectangular boundary, you might be able to align/warp/scale the different images so that all boxes are in the same places for each form. Then you need to manually define the positions of all boxes once and cut those out from all forms. Maybe [this](http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/) and/or [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html) can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a OCR(Optical Character Recognition) issue,opencv is not good at it, you can try tesseract https://github.com/tesseract-ocr

Comment: this is — at best — a comment, not an answer